# Is there any difference in implied nuances between "make every effort" and "make all efforts"?

Tags: phrase-choice

Some dictionaries like *[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make%20every%20effort)* and *[The Freedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+every+effort+to+do)* define the phrase "**make every effort**" in them while no dictionaries, including the two, have "**make all efforts**" in their word lists. Both of them are, however, often seen in newspapers, magazines, email correspondences etc., and I'm wondering if there is any difference in implied nuances between them. For instance, what would be the difference between the following two sentences, if any?

- We will *make every effort* to ensure the safety and quality of our products.
- We will *make all efforts* to ensure the safety and quality of our products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Make every effort” is much more idiomatic, perhaps due to the following.

The only slight nuance I can detect is that “all efforts” has the feel of knowing all of the “efforts” one could make when the statement is made, whereas “every effort” feels more like one is saying, if any opportunity presents itself, I will take it.